# Android Marshmallow damage stored data and block write to internal sd card

Tags: android, storage, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm developing application that is targeted for API 18. Application download data by Bluetooth and GSM and stores data on internal sdcard (usually \emulated\sdcard - readed by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`).

Till this time everything works fine - files and folders are correctly saved.
Today i've faced very strange behaviour:

1) Started the app, and it works for over an hour and store data files.

2) After that, i've closed app and want to download data to the computer.
   Before plugin USB, I've used Android file explorer software to check stored data.

I was shocked - new folder (any new data) was gone! 
It's like system removes or hide all files and data created in last app session.

Remarks: application don't have procedures for deletion folder or files. Also it works good on previous versions of Android (mostly 4.X and 5.X).

It's very strange because app has warning mechanism when save isn't possible and that warnings wasn't displayed. So I think, write was allowed by system, but data isn't visible at this moment.

Another stranger thing is that application can't write any file in internal storage from this moment (and the warnings are displayed as should in this case).

It looks like Android Marshmallow "decides" in particular moment - your new data won't be available anymore, and your app won't write to internal card.
I've checked app permissions in system - OK.

Any ideas, why this happens? How to deal with it?

Comment: Marshmallow permissions are different than previous version . You have to set run time permissions for marshmallow or allow manually in app permissions in setting.

Comment: I know that, but at this moment migration to Android Studio is not possible (project is in Eclipse with use of NDK for older API). At current IDE (Eclipse) I don't have access to run-time permission functions - can't refer to API23, only API18.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to these guides for managing permissions during runtime: http://www.howtogeek.com/230683/how-to-manage-app-permissions-on-android-6.0/

https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Did it work for API18? ContexCompat not available - can't use code for that, and migration to API23 is not possible at the moment.

Comment: It doesnt work for api 18 I think because ContextCompat is available in api 23. If you are running your app in marshmallow, you should consider migrating to api 23 to support the latest changes in android environment.

Comment: Migration isn't possible - too expensive.